# EditText checking

Tags: android, if-statement, android-edittext

I'm trying to check an EditText value, but the application crashes.
How can I handle my EditText?

```
        String stra_txt = edit_1.getText().toString();
        boolean first = false;
        if (stra_txt.equals("1") || stra_txt.equals("0"))
            {
                first = true;
            }
        else
            {
                first = false;
            }

        if(first = true)
            zheg();
        else
        {System.exit(0);}
```

this code does not work too:

```
        String stra_txt = edit_1.getText().toString();

        if (stra_txt.equals("1") || stra_txt.equals("0"))
            {
                zheg();
            }
        else
            {
                System.exit(0);
            }
```

upd.

I've found solution:

```
                if (edit_1.getText().toString().equals("")){
                        finish();
                }
                else 
                {
                    zheg();
                }
```

Comment: What you are getting in your logcat? Can you add the logcat error with this question?

Comment: post logcat and add `toString().trim();`

Comment: Make sure, your EditText ins't null!

Comment: **WILD GUESS** You're probably getting a `NullPointerException`. Please post your complete logcat to confirm that.

Answer (score 0):

Use try Catch Block its get actual error or app crash

```
 try
      {
          String stra_txt = edit_1.getText().toString();
          boolean first = false;
          boolean second = false;
          if (stra_txt.equals("1") || stra_txt.equals("0"))
          {
              first = true;
          }
          else
          {
              first = false;
          }

          if(first = true)
              zheg();
          else
          {System.exit(0);}
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you have linked your EditText id with XML

```
EditText edit_1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_1);
```

if you have given this, then there must be a problem with zheg() method.

Please post your logs here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
if(edit_1 != null){
    String stra_txt = edit_1.getText().toString();
    if ((stra_txt.equals("1") || stra_txt.equals("0")){
        zheg();
    }else{
        // System.exit(0);
        finish();
    }
}
```

if this prevents your app from getting crashed then probably you may not be initializing the view. Add this line before the above code:

```
edit_1 = (EditText)findViewById(YOUR_VIEW_ID);
```

Comment: your variant particullary works, app is not crashing, but `code`if()`code` not working, only block with `code`else`code` - current activity getting closed.

Comment: Whats your input in the EditText?

Comment: `android:inputType="numberSigned"` 16 numbers, which  takes only 0 and 1 values

Comment: when i'm changing `System.exit(0);` to `finish()`, i may saw my empty dialog window for a short moment. But it must not be empty.